# Training svm classifier with non ordinal text features

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am really unable to find how can I train a svm classifier with text features that are non ordinal and can be any possible string of characters.
I am using a labelled dataset like this in a row.

> Tajmahal   | India  |   21-08-1990

Now for dates I am using toordinal()  function for training but clueless about the feature extraction for strings.

Comment: read [some examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should map each of the distinct values of the string columns to a numerical label. Then, create columns for these labels and assign 0/1 depending on the prescence of the corresponding string value for that row.
This is called **One Hot Encoding**. You should checkout Scikit-learn's [CategoricalEncoding](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder.html) class. It does most of the work for you.